# Inherited Attributes and EF Code First Dynamic Proxy

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

My question is related to [this](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/184) issue.
I have a POCO class with virtual navigation property from the child to the parent. The parent has a collection of children.

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string ParentID { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Now... you guessed it - I try to serialize the parent that comes from EF(i.e. the proxy) with the XmlSerializer. It first complains about all unkown types(the dynamically generated classes) which I handle somehow. But then it exepts with a 'circular reference' exception.

The reason after some investigation turns out to be that the XmlIgnore attribute is not discoverable via reflection on the proxy object's Parent property.

```
    Type.GetType("System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Child_2C9351FD5E156D94E5BF2C68DABFC2A956181C99A0C2E4E6B592E6373D8645ED, EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
.GetProperty("Parent").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlIgnoreAttribute), true) <-- returns 'None'
```

The proxy object's type base type is my Child class. The `XmlIgnoreAttribute` doesn't set the Inherited flag, and the default is true, so this should work. What is happening?

Is the proxy object lying about it's base type?

How can I workaround this issue without writing 'manual' xml serialization(I need to use the XmlSerializer).

**UPDATE**:
It turns out that the XMLSerializer doesn't respect the 'inheritness' of the attributes which seems wrong. Is that a bug or is it by design?

Comment: Let's say you can serialize the proxy. What do you do next? How you are going to use it? Would it work on a different machine? Would it work if you restart you app? I don't remember from top of my head how the type name is generated but it might be different each time you start the app. Also, proxies have a reference to a type that is not serializable. If you need to serialize entities you should disable proxy creation.

Comment: I just remembered that XmlSerializer does not serialize private fields/properties so the comment about the private field/object that is not serializable is wrong - it should not matter for XmlSerialization.

Comment: @Pawel - I just need to create XML from the proxy. I use other attributes as well - XmlRootAttribute for example, so the XML will look exactly as if the POCO object has been serialized. By the way I already solved my issue by implementing IXmlSerializable. Still curious about this one though.

Comment: This is what I wanted to suggest - IXmlSerializable. It's a bit painful to implement though (did it once)...

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx) msdn article (remarks section):

'This method ignores the inherit parameter for properties and events. To search the inheritance chain for attributes on properties and events, use the appropriate overloads of the Attribute.GetCustomAttributes method.'

So this does not have to do anything with proxies. Take a look at this example:

```
public class Test
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual int Property { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Test
{
    public override int Property { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            typeof(Derived)
           .GetProperty("Property")
           .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlIgnoreAttribute), true)
           .Count());

        Console.WriteLine(
           Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(
               typeof(Derived)
              .GetProperty("Property"), true)
              .Count());
    }
}
```

and the results:

```
0
1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I completely agree with you, I'm not sure if the XMLSerializer uses this exact method but I made a test to serialize a Derived object and the Property is serialized. Which means that the XMLSerializer doesn't respect the attribute on the base class for whatever reason. I updated the question.